# Unable to completely deselect all objects in Blender (using scripting or key A)

Tags: python, blender

I have a long tube with several tiny cylinder patches perpendicular to the surface of the tube. I have been try to write a script to combine everything together using boolean modifier and then remove the tiny cylinders so that there is only one mesh consisting of a tube with tiny cylinders (for future FEA). After creating these cylinders, I saved this blender file, with the last cylinder being active. Afterwards, no matter what I did, I can't seem to deselect this last cylinder (as shown in the pic: [i can't seem to get rid of the orange dot, which i thought it was fine but it weren't](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFDJY.png)). Thus, when i tried to run the following code:

```
import bpy  
import bmesh
import mathutils 

bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

# tried to rename the first cylinder, but the last cylinder was renamed instead
bpy.ops.object.select_pattern(pattern = 'Cylinder')
bpy.context.object.data.name = 'Cylinder.000'

bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
bpy.ops.object.select_pattern(pattern = 'Cylinder.000')

# tried to remesh the first cylinder, but the last one was remeshed instead
bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='REMESH')
bpy.context.object.modifiers["Remesh"].scale = 0.5
bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(apply_as='DATA', modifier="Remesh")

bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
bpy.ops.object.select_pattern(pattern = 'tube')

# tried to combine the first cylinder and the tube, but two cylinders were combined instead
bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='BOOLEAN')
bpy.context.object.modifiers["Boolean"].object = bpy.data.objects['Cylinder.000']   
bpy.context.object.modifiers["Boolean"].operation = 'UNION'
bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(apply_as='DATA', modifier="Boolean")

# reselect the first cylinder and delete it (the only one worked!!!)
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
bpy.ops.object.select_pattern(pattern = 'Cylinder.000')
bpy.ops.object.delete()
```

Comment: SOLVED! Upon suggestion from a friend, I realised I forgot to make the selected object active first.... Never in a million years would I have thought of this..... For those who are interested, the code is bpy.context.scene.objects.active = bpy.data.objects['Cylinder']

Answer (score 17):

Here's an update for 2.8 which reduces the iteration to selected objects.

```
for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    obj.select_set(False)
```

Or you could just call

```
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
```

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old post but, for anyone else that wanted to deselect all objects I do it like this:

For Blender **2.8** onward:

```
for obj in bpy.data.objects:
    obj.select_set(False)
```

For Blender **2.79** and earlier:

```
for obj in bpy.data.objects:
    obj.select = False
```

Answer (score 3):

Dfelinto showed me a cool trick to make all objects inActive.

```
bpy.context.scene.objects.active = None
```

Comment: @MasterJames But it still helped me because it is so closely related